# Check that list of tuples has tuple with 1st element as defined string

Tags: python, list, parsing, tuples

I'm parsing HTML and I need to get only tags with selector like `div.content`.

For parsing I'm using [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html). I'm so far that I get list of tags' attributes.

It looks something like this:

`[('class', 'content'), ('title', 'source')]`

The problem is that I don't know how to check that:

1. List have tuple with 1st element called `class`,
2. Values of tuples 1st element (it will be 2nd element) is `content`;

I know this is easy question, but I'm quite new with Python as well. Thanks in any advice!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When looping through your elements:

```
if ('class', 'content') in element_attributes:
    #do stuff
```

Comment: How about if you want this condition to match on a wild-card on the second element?

Comment: What if you don't know the second element in the tuple ? I want something like: if ('key','anyvalue') in list_of_tuples.
Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [('class', 'content'), ('title', 'source')]

('class', 'content') in l
```

returns True, because there is at least one tuple with 'class' as first and 'content' as second element.

You can now use it:

```
if ('class', 'content') in l:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that HTML 'class' attributes are allowed to be a space separated list of css classes.  E.g., you can do `<span class='green big'>...</span>`.  It sounds like what you really want to know is whether a given HTML element has a specific CSS class (given a list of (attribute,value) pairs).  In that case, I would use something like this:

```
element_attributes =  [('class', 'content'), ('title', 'source')]
is_content = any((attr=='class') and ('content' in val.split())
                 for (attr, val) in element_attributes)
```

Of course, if you know for certain that all elements you care about will have only one CSS class, then sr2222's answer is better/simpler.

Answer (score 1):

For check if one of the tuple element has some value you could use filter function:

```
tuples_list = [('class', 'content'), ('title', 'source')]
if filter(lambda a: a[0] == 'class', tuples_list):
    # your code goes here
if filter(lambda a: a[1] == 'content', tuples_list):
    # your code goes here
```

The filter gives you all tuples that match your conditions:

```
values = filter(lambda a: a[1] == 'content', tuples_list)
# values == [('class', 'content')]
```

If you are sure that they are in the same tuple:

```
if ('class', 'content') in tuples_list:
    # your code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

1st question)

```
if len(list) > 1:
    if list[0][0] == 'class':
        return True`
```

2nd question)

```
for elem in list:
    if elem[1] == 'content':
        return True
```

note: from what I understood, the 2nd question means that if ONE of the 2nd tuple values is 'content', you want true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = [('class', 'content'), ('title', 'source')]
check = False
for item in l:
  if item[0] == 'class':
    check=True
    print item[1]
print "List have tuple with 1st element called class: %s" check
```