# Check list of tuples where first element of tuple is specified by defined string

Tags: python, list, tuples, wildcard, element

This question is similar to [Check that list of tuples has tuple with 1st element as defined string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703088/check-that-list-of-tuples-has-tuple-with-1st-element-as-defined-string) but no one has properly answered the "wildcard" question.

Say I have `[('A', 2), ('A', 1), ('B', 0.2)]`

And I want to identify the tuples where the FIRST element is A. How do I return just the following?

`[('A', 2), ('A', 1)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Python's [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) function for this as follows:

```
l = [('A', 2), ('A', 1), ('B', 0.2)]
print filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'A', l)
```

Giving:

```
[('A', 2), ('A', 1)]
```

Comment: Great use of filter and the lambda function. Thank you! And thank you for adding the link to the other question! I will do that in the future...(rookie mistake).

Answer (score 6):

Using a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [('A', 2), ('A', 1), ('B', 0.2)]
>>> print([el for el in l if el[0] == 'A'])
[('A', 2), ('A', 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple enough list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [('A', 2), ('A', 1), ('B', 0.2)]
>>> [(x,y) for (x,y) in L if x == 'A']
[('A', 2), ('A', 1)]
```